# Call AWS CloundFront API with CURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to call AWS CloundFront API with CURL? I would like to trigger an invalidation without installing much dependency. But I'm unable to make a simple GET request to the API:

```
curl -v -X GET \
-H "Date: $(date -R)" \
-H "Authorization: AWS ${CLOUDFRONT_ACCESS_KEY}:$(echo -en ${CLOUDFRONT_ACCESS_KEY} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${CLOUDFRONT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} -binary | base64)" \
https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2020-05-31/distribution/EMC3WW4JXXXXX/invalidation/IXMUICGG7L77A
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2020-05-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>IncompleteSignature</Code>
    <Message>Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization=AWS AKIAJG77PBXLMN5YQI7A:K62YyDlWiVf/yr44YSs7BbsQYDQ=</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>f9e5b7de-bce6-4bfd-951e-2986ae5bc1a3</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [Signing AWS requests with Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) for signing the request.

Plus the invalidation API call needs more params for making the call as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInvalidation.html)

I usually keep this handy [s3-rest-api-with-curl](https://czak.pl/2015/09/15/s3-rest-api-with-curl.html)